# Angular Electron app refreshes with blank screen on file change save

Tags: angular, electron

I am developing my Angular web app and importing it into an Electron App. I run my web app from the url http://localhost:4200 and link to that from the Window I create in my electron app's main.ts file (when I am developing). I have set a default route, and that route opens when I start first my web app and then my electron app. I can navigate around to different pages and it works fine. However when I make a change in a file and save or when I select "reload" from the menu in the app, the electron app refreshes with a blank screen. I get the below errors in Dev Tools' console.

```
GET http://localhost:4200/library/(grid/0//sidebar:libar/styles.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
0):14 
        
        
GET http://localhost:4200/library/(grid/0//sidebar:libar/polyfills.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
0):14 
        
        
GET http://localhost:4200/library/(grid/0//sidebar:libar/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

The routes in my web app get pretty complex because I use mutliple router outlets and pass parameters into each. It looks like electron is treating the url for the currently loaded page as a base and is trying to load styles, polyfills, and main file. The first time the app loads it loads files:

```
http://localhost:4200/styles.css
http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js
http://localhost:4200/main.js
```

(I have tried both electron-reload and electron-reloader packages to refresh the app) How do I either reset the applicaiton totally so it points to the original default route and loads the files correctly, or keep the current route and load the files correctly?